# NodeJS/Express JS route protection

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I know that the most common methods to protect a server API route is to use authentication tokens such as `JWT` and usage of CORS. The way I believe protection of routes with `JWT` tokens works is by having the client side send a server-side signed JWT in the `req.headers`, before having the server verify the JWT and check if it is allowed access.

However, I have noticed one problem with this approach. Since the client side network activities are able to be seen by anyone, it means that the `JWT` token could be viewed by anyone by analyzing the `req.headers`. This would then allow them to take the `JWT` token and send spam request to the server, while the server would not be able to differentiate if its a malicious one or legit one and still allow access.

Even with the usage of CORS, anyone would still be able to access the route through `cURL` or `Postman`, hence still being able to send false and malicious requests.

Have anyone thought of this before, and perhaps found a solution? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Not an expert here but I believe that's why JWT must be renewed every short period of time (like every 5 minutes or less)

Comment: Who exactly do you think can see the  client-side network activities?  If you're using https for the transport, then the ONLY one who can see those activities is someone ON the actual client computer and you've already authorized that person to make some requests to your server.  If you want to prevent misuse of that, then you implement rate limiting, spam detection, token expiration and more granular access control (allowing access to only specific routes with a given token).

Comment: @jfriend00 Does your idea of token expiration refers to the same concept as Rodolfo BocaneGra? Thank for your other suggestions too!

Comment: FYI, the way the browser architecture works, it is not theoretically possible to allow your browser page to make a specific API request using a token, but to block other requests for that same API coming from the same client (even if they are from custom client code that is not in your web page).  Custom code can "pretend" to be from a browser and you can't really tell that on your server.

Comment: Token expiration is just one aspect of this type of security that makes it difficult to grab a token from the web page and then use it elsewhere and for a long time.  It's not a solution all by itself.  It's one component of a solution.  The concept is no different than implementing expiration on cookies used for authentication.  Same thing.  You can't make the expiration too short or there are problems with usability.

Comment: The way I plan to use `JWT` token is that when a user logs in, the server would sign an object containing the user's basic info, before returning to client side. If token expiration were to be used, would the client side need to constantly send request to the server to retrieve a new token?

Comment: Your server has to defend itself against malicious requests.  This is the responsibility of your server, not of some token mechanism.  If a properly authenticated user decides to attempt something malicious on its own behalf, your server has to detect that and prevent that.  Typically, all an authenticated user should be able to do is affect their OWN data so the damage they can do is limited.  The server already has to defend against denial of service attacks and should not allow one authenticated user to wreck data that does not belong to that user.

Comment: `Since the client side network activities are able to be seen by anyone` - Why are you not protecting your requests with https?

Comment: @slebetman I plan to use AWS lambda, which I believe automatically deploys HTTPS. Correct me if I'm wrong. However, I believe even with the HTTPS, anyone would still be able to view the `req.headers`

Comment: No - not anyone.  Only someone with access directly to the client computer.  Anyone outside the client computer cannot see through the https.  And, you've already authorized the user on the client to make requests with the token.  It seems to me you're operating with some false assumptions here.

Comment: @jfriend00 Oh yes regarding your recent comment. I am not actually worried that a user would affect the data of other users, but actually more towards that user overusing a service example `geocoding` service defined in the server, due to their privilege of having the token. Which I believe could be solved with your previous answer of using rate limiting and spam detection. Or perhaps with expiration token too.

Comment: @jfriend00 Oh alright got it, thank you for the clarifications!

Comment: Have you heard about  TCP/IP and how it works ? On each request the ip of the client is send to the server how about if you encode the ip among the users that so  when your server gets the token it can compare the ip of who is requesting and the ip in which the token was created. Theory is not there to make your life harder, but to make it easier

Comment: @Ernesto Yes I have heard of it, but what are you exactly referring to?

Comment: Overusing a geocoding service needs to be protected by rate limiting implemented on the server so a given authorized client is only allowed to use your service an "appropriate" amount where you have to define and enforce the appropriate amount on the server.  You may also want to detect patterns of misuse that would never be done by your own app such as rapid fire requests for a bunch of different locations.

Comment: @jfriend00 Oh thank you for your advice on rate limiting! Would give it a try!

Comment: @Ernesto Oh, so if I understand it correctly. Do you mean to create an ip-token system, such that each client ip address is linked to a certain token (Which is created for that certain ip address), but a request from another ip address with the same token would be denied access?

Comment: No, tokens are not shared, one user can have many devices, a device can have one token, then that means one user can have many tokens when a user signs in you a token is created, but not only the token should be created, you need to have a table in your data base that contains the ip of the device, the token created, the user who created the token, and some of the user agent and platform details used, when you login in Facebook, on your laptop and in your phone each of them have there unique token and Facebook knows those two devices belongs to you

Comment: Oh alright thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

Just generate csrfToken to the view that may call the API, and send the csrfToken along with the request.

https://github.com/expressjs/csurf

server

```
const csrfProtection = csrf({ cookie: true })

app.get('/submitFormPage', csrfProtection, function (req, res) {
  // pass the csrfToken to the view
  res.render('send', { csrfToken: req.csrfToken() })
})

app.post('/process', parseForm, csrfProtection, function (req, res) {
  res.send('data is being processed')
})
```

client

It will call the /submitFormPage before rendering this page.

```
<form action="/process" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{csrfToken}}">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: So am I right to say that this technique works the same way as `JWT` token but with a `csrfToken` instead?

Comment: JWT is usually for authentication and csrfToken is like when you are calling some API you can use it to protect. And csrfToken will change every time when rendering the page.